# POST Model to Controller Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I've been learning MVC 3 rapidly over the last couple weeks but something's come up that I just haven't been able to solve searching for hours.  I'm developing a simple shopping cart and I'm trying to pass data in a linear path through the checkout process.  I've been unable to get a model to POST to the next view no matter what I try.

To start with, the 'Cart' entity is being pulled from Session using an implementation of IModelBinder.  It's essentially available for any method.  It's been working great for a while.  My issue is trying to pass the same model between /cart/confirm and /cart/checkout.

**Can someone help figure out why the model is always empty in the controller for /cart/checkout?**

```
public class CartController : Controller
{

public ActionResult Index (Cart cart)
{
   //Works fine, anonymous access to the cart
   return View(cart);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Confirm (Cart cart)
{
   //Turn 'Cart' from session (IModelBinder) into a 'Entities.OrderDetail'
   OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
   orderDetail.SubTotal = cart.ComputeTotalValue();
   ...
   ...
   return View(orderDetail);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Checkout(OrderDetail model)
{
   //PROBLEM: model is always null here.
}

}
```

/Views/Cart/Index.aspx looks like this (sorry, no Razor):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site-1-Panel.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<My.Namespace.Entities.Cart>" %>
...
...
<% using(Html.BeginForm("confirm", "cart")) { %>

Not much to see here, just a table with the cart line items

<input type="submit" value="Check Out" />
<% } %>
```

I suspect the problem is here, but I've tried every variation of Html.BeginForm() I can try and can't get the model to pass to /cart/checkout.  Anyway, /Views/Cart/Confirm.aspx looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site-1-Panel.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<My.Namespace.Entities.OrderDetail>" %>
...
...
<% using (Html.BeginForm("checkout", "cart", Model)) { %>
<%: Model.DBUserDetail.FName %>
<%: Model.DBUserDetail.LName %>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DBOrder.ShippingMethod, new { @value = "UPS Ground" })%>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DBOrder.ShippingAmount, new { @value = "29.60" })%>
...
...
<input type="submit" value="Confirm &amp; Pay" />
<% } %>
```

And finally /Views/Cart/Checkout.aspx looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site-1-Panel.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<My.Namespace.Entities.OrderDetail>" %>
...
...
<%: Html.Hidden("x_first_name", Model.DBUserDetail.FName) %>
<%: Html.Hidden("x_last_name", Model.DBUserDetail.LName) %>
...
It doesn't really matter what's here, an exception gets throw in the controller because the model is always null
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your model state is invalid. [Add this extension method](http://pastebin.com/S0gM3vqg) and call it on the first line of the action like:

```
ModelState.DumpErrors();
```

Put a breakpoint one line after it and examine the Output window for more information about what is wrong with the binding.

Edit - The full extension method:

```
public static class ModelExtensions
{
    public static void DumpErrors(this System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
    {
        var errors = from key in ModelState
                     let errorList = ModelState[key.Key].Errors
                     where errorList.Any()
                     select new
                     {
                         Item = key.Key,
                         Value = key.Value,
                         errorList
                     };

        foreach (var errorList in errors)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MODEL ERROR:");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorList.Item);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorList.Value);
            foreach (var error in errorList.errorList)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.Exception);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did teach me a great way to find model errors and it certainly put me in the right direction.  It's a problem with my 'Entities.OrderDetail' that I'm trying to use as a model.  That entity  just holds 2 public objects, both are Linq to SQL objects.  Maybe I can't use that as a model, have to use POCO objects?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know asp specifically, but it seems like you have access to cart in index and confirm b/c you are passing it explicitly. Since you are not passing it to checkout, you would not be able to access it. I might be totally off

Comment: The issue isn't accessing the cart object, it's available anytime I want it because of my IModelBinder implementation.  I'm getting a null **OrderDetail**.  I think asawyer has pointed me in the right direction below though...